# JAVA thread allocation?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

My program run in Eclipse, all process will be done in a single thread only. I am facing a problem when i deploy it to client machine (I am not sure the configuration of the machine).

Thread is suddenly changed  from `btpool0-1` to `btpool0-7 during the process. I am sure i have not create any thread in coding.

I would like to know is there any reason why the behavior like this??

Thanks in advance!!

> =======LOG HERE=====================================================
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.784 [btpool0-1] INFO
>   hk.com.xx.sys.service.impl.BargeVoyageServiceImpl - End submit request
>   to nSys in saveAndSynchronize
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.TransactionCoordinator - Flush before
>   Commit Transaction id 1656368712 in thread 2055564603
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.DefaultEntityManager - Run flush for
>   delegate 481556314 of customFramework manager 1801910956 in thread
>   2055564603 in session 1798587502 in transaction 2028663310 in context
>   880330942 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.ro.security.remote.RemotecustomFrameworkManager - Run
>   flush for delegate 1470155242 of customFramework manager 146387751 in
>   thread 2055564603 in session 2099793559 in transaction 1484449171 in
>   context 1631574962
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.TransactionCoordinator - Commit
>   Transaction id 1656368712 in thread 2055564603
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.DefaultcustomFrameworkManager - Committed
>   transaction for delegate 481556314 of customFramework manager
>   1801910956 in thread 2055564603 in session 1798587502 in transaction
>   2028663310 in context 880330942
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.DefaultcustomFrameworkManager - Closed
>   delegate 481556314 for customFramework manager 1801910956 in thread
>   2055564603 in session 1798587502
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.ro.security.remote.RemotecustomFrameworkManager -
>   Committed transaction for delegate 1470155242 of customFramework
>   manager 146387751 in thread 2055564603 in session 2099793559 in
>   transaction 1484449171 in context 1631574962
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.ro.security.remote.RemotecustomFrameworkManager -
>   Closed delegate 1470155242 for customFramework manager 146387751 in
>   thread 2055564603 in session 2099793559
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.TransactionCoordinator - Commit
>   Transaction Ended id 1656368712 in thread 2055564603
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:58.877 [btpool0-1] INFO performance -
>   hk.com.xx.sys.service.BargeVoyageService method
>   saveAndSynchronizeForPeakMode - elapsed time is 687 ms.
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.190 [btpool0-1] DEBUG
>   HK.com.xx.ro.security.ThreadSecurityContext - stack.size() = 1; index
>   = 0
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.252 [btpool0-7] INFO
>   customFramework.service.http.HttpServiceHandlerFactory - Invoking
>   service hk.com.xx.sys.service.BargeVoyageService method
>   savePeakBargeVoyageInBatch
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.252 [btpool0-7] DEBUG
>   customFramework.service.http.HttpServiceHandlerFactory - Service
>   object =
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.252 [btpool0-7] DEBUG
>   customFramework.service.ServiceInterceptorFactory - Invoking method
>   savePeakBargeVoyageInBatch with transaction attribute = REQUIRED
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.252 [btpool0-7] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.TransactionCoordinator - Execute with
>   transaction attribute = REQUIRED
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.252 [btpool0-7] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.TransactionCoordinator - Begin Transaction
>   id 1656368712 in thread 1377751019
>
> 2016-01-20 12:03:59.252 [btpool0-7] DEBUG
>   customFramework.persistence.DefaultcustomFrameworkManager - Created
>   delegate 1334851109 for customFramework manager 1801910956 in thread
>   1377751019 in session 80928754 in context 812419927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do use a pool - `btpool0-7` reads as thread #7 of pool #0. Now, this does *not* mean that you've started 6 threads - it just means that your pool is sized at least 8 threads large, and for some random reason thread #7 was chosen to start the unit of work. This could be due to a number of reasons that I won't enumerate here, suffice to say that a) it's benign, b) you should not care about the number, just that it stays the same during logging.

Comment: Why did the thread number change when invoke any other method?? I have not this issue in my development environment.

I ask this question because **threadlocal variable** is used in the program. The thread number change to forced some data unsynchronize problem.

Comment: the first log line with a different thread ID mentions 'customFramework.service.http.HttpServiceHandlerFactory' - so perhaps you're servicing some HTTP request there?

Comment: I am not sure when will invoke http request because most of process is handled by the company framework. At least i have not invoke http request in programming.

A few question i would ask..

1. That means a new thread will be created if the method is called via http request???

2. Is it possible different OS with different thread behavior? It is because in my development environment, all process is finished in a same thread. 

Thanks!

Comment: 1) In all probability, the thread has already been created - see if you can connect with VisualVM to see the thread names. 2) Yes; you can also have different versions of Java with different HashMap implementations changing the order of threads; you can also have different pool sizes in development and production.

However, why do you care? Your ThreadLocal should isolate the threads; if you need cross-thread access, use some kind of identifier.

Comment: We are facing a issue when a value is store in threadlocal at saveAndSynchronizeForPeakMode method [btpool0-1]. After that, we have to get the value at savePeakBargeVoyageInBatch [btpool0-7]. The problem is... we can't get the value because of the thread is changed. As you mentioned, threadlocal isolated the thread.

Thanks your help~~~!

Comment: Keep in mind that if don't use a ThreadLocal, you can only do this procedure one instance at a time; while I'm also recommending the Singleton pattern to manage the intermediate storage, I'm also feeling that  this cross-thread usage of intermediate storage exposes an architectural flaw in your design.